# Change of url address after clicking on the activation link in the email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I make my project in Laravel 5.8.
I would like to change the url which is sent in the activation email (after registering a new user account) from:

```
http://domain.test/email/verify/4? Expires = 1564173078 & signature = 60f6d062f9e52fcc79ffddaa5d82e46cf7fe9b748018ea9ff05bc6b4bf310f9b
```

to the following:

```
http://domain.test/activation/4? expires = 1564173078 & signature = 60f6d062f9e52fcc79ffddaa5d82e46cf7fe9b748018ea9ff05bc6b4bf310f9b
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you mean from /email/verify/ to /activation/ ?

Comment: yes. I want change url with original to my

Comment: does it helps you? If it does, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

First you need to de-register the verification route

```php
Auth::routes(['verify' => false]);
```

Then register this routes instead. Change the path according to your needs

```php
Route::get('email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
Route::get('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
```

You may compare the routes before and after by issuing this artisan command

```
php artisan route:list
```